# Parametros para uma Container View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone, swift

O cenário é o seguinte:

> Eu possuo uma `UIViewController` e dentro desta controladora eu possuo
>   uma `UITableViewController` adicionado como uma `ContainerView`.

Como eu faço para passar parâmetros entre a minha `UIViewController` e a minha `ContainerView`?

Por exemplo, eu quero passar da minha `UIViewController` uma lista de itens para serem apresentados na minha `ContainerView` (`UITableViewController`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você simplesmente ter um método público na sua `UITableViewController` e executá-lo pelo `UIViewController`. Vamos supor que sua `UITableViewController` tenha o seguinte método no seu cabeçalho:

```
- (void)preencheTabela:(NSArray *)lista;
```

E a implementação:

```
- (void)preencheTabela:(NSArray *)lista {
    // TODO preencher sua lista atual com a recuperada
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

E no seu `UIViewController`, uma vez que você tenha a referência do `Controller` com a tabela que foi inserida no *container*, basta executar o seu método:

```
[self.referanciaTabela preencheTabela:listaEnviada];
```

Esclarecendo que não é para o *container* que você vai passar, e sim para o `Controller` que está dentro do *container*. Ficou claro?

---

Sua referência, já com o container adicionado a partir do *storyboard*, fica mais ou menos assim, no `viewDidLoad:` por exemplo:

```
self.referanciaTabela = [self.childViewControllers firstObject];
```

Comment: Sim, entendi, porém a minha dúvida é que ela ja esta criada via storyboard, ai ela automaticamente ja esta dentro desta container. Então eu não tenho o Controller da minha container instanciada na minha UIViewController

Comment: Certo, não tem problema já que é só obter a referência no `viewDidLoad:` com o primeiro elemento do `childViewControllers`. Adicionei uma edição na minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo aqui, primeira vez trabalhando com Container View fiquei meio perido